# Incorrect tamil characters in a page outside wordpress

Tags: wordpress, programming-languages, wordpress-theming, tamil

I have a site using tamil language. I have no problem with displaying tamil characters inside wordpress. I have created a page outside wordpress in which i embed wordpress functions by using wp-load.php however, it displays incorrect tamil characters.

How to fix this issue? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the meta charset tag in the `<head>` of your WP site. Should look something like `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`, but it might not be `UTF-8`  Paste that into the head of your other site.